# Highlighted property is only for display within Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

How do I solve such warning? What does it mean in most of the cases?

When I click on it, there is nothing highlighted on my Interface Builder (it just zooms in on some area between 2 view controllers).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a UIImageView with **Highlighted** set to true in Xcode. Xcode tells you that the value is for WYSIWYG but won't work at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I've already realized that shortly after posting the question (couldn't post answer then). In some case IB doesn't point you to the right `UIImageView` though and you have to look for it one by one.

Comment: Great that they won't tell you which one of the bazillion items has highlighting turned on....

Comment: To find the needle in the haystack, you can right click your Storyboard->Open As->Source Code, then search for highlighted="YES"

Comment: @Keller **Thank you so much for the trick**, this was the perfect help for me :)

Answer (score 11):

After looking at warning message details I got to know, but still there was no way, I could find particular Image is having `highlighted="YES"`

**Perfect Trick suggested by @[Keller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625709/keller)** in Accepted answer's comment.

> Just right click your Storyboard --> Open As --> Source Code.

search for

> highlighted="YES

Just set YES to **NO**.

*or event if you look carefully code around searched string, you can get in which ViewController's Scene particular ImageView.*

Thanks to @[Keller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625709/keller)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your **Storyboard -> Open as -> Source Code**.
Search for *highlighted = "YES"*.
Check the name of the image.
Find the image on the **Storyboard**.
Click the image, go to **Show the Attributes inspector**.
Uncheck the **Highlighted** option

[Highlighted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEJgt.png)