# UIImageView state isHighlighted set to true in storyboard but when view is loaded, is set to false

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I feel like I've done this a hundred times and it is suddenly not working. Help me see if I'm missing something.

In my storyboard, I created a UIImageView with an image and a highlighted image. I checked the State Highlighted box and the storyboard correctly shows that UIImageView with the highlighted image.

When I run the code in the simulator, the UIImageView is showing the unhighlighted image. In viewDidLoad(), when I print out the value of the isHighlighted property, it is false.

Why is my setting in the storyboard getting lost?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    print("checkmark is highlighted: \(self.checkmarkPMTAdditional.isHighlighted)")

}
```

Output:

```
checkmark is highlighted: false
```

I have confirmed that if I programmatically set the `.isHighlighted=true` that the correct highlighted image shows up, but I want this to be set in the storyboard. I double checked the UIImageView documentation and it says the State value is supposed to be configurable in Interface Builder (i.e. the storyboard).

What am I missing? Why is my UIImageView being loaded with `isHighlighted=false` when I've configured it to be `=true` in the storyboard?

[image: screenshot of attributes panel for uiimageview]

[image: screenshot showing the UIImageView is connected to an IBOutlet]

[UIImageView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) says that the State (Highlighted) can be configured in the Storyboard.

[image: screenshot of UIImageView Documentation]

Comment: You should be getting a warning that says "warning: Highlighted property is only for display within Interface Builder (The value set for this property will not be present at runtime)".

Comment: Gah. I see it now in the warnings list, thank you. Since when has this been true? The documentation explicitly says this value can be set in the Storyboard. I'll update the post above to include a screenshot of that. :/

Comment: I'm not sure, but at least since 8 years ago because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009389/highlighted-property-is-only-for-display-within-interface-builder/16430591) containing the warning was posted in 2013.